# С# WPF Слайдер в % изменение 4х значений сразу

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, textbox

Есть 4 textbox или 4 NumericUpDown с разными значениями (1.5, 2.6, 0.8, 1.3)
При передвижении слайдера надо чтобы все эти значения изменялись пропорционально. т.е. если слайдер на середине 50% то числа становились 0.75 1.3 0.4 0.65 если на 0 то все значения 0, если на 75% то 75% от числа. Как это реализовать?

к 4ем textbox прикрепил slider, на этом всё

```
<TextBox x:Name="Tb1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="129,329,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="33" Text="{Binding ElementName=SliderRecoil, StringFormat={}{0:0.##}, Path=Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="Tb2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="167,329,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="33" Text="{Binding ElementName=SliderRecoil, StringFormat={}{0:0.##}, Path=Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="Tb3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="205,329,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="33" Text="{Binding ElementName=SliderRecoil, StringFormat={}{0:0.##}, Path=Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="Tb4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="243,329,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="33" Text="{Binding ElementName=SliderRecoil, StringFormat={}{0:0.##}, Path=Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: выглядит как техзадание. Проблема то в чем?

Comment: Проблема в том что я не имею не малейшего понятия как это реализовать)

Comment: а как вы пробовали это реализовать? Чтобы ответить мне ставьте плиз мой ник вот так @tym32167

Comment: @tym32167 к 4ем textbox прикрепил slider Text="{Binding ElementName=SliderRecoil, StringFormat={}{0:0.##}, Path=Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
Указал максимальное и минимальное значение для текст бокса, на этом моменте у меня стопор

Comment: все подобные детали добавляйте в вопрос - чтобы тот. кто прочитает вопрос сразу видел всю информацию, что касается вопроса.

Comment: Ну и интересно, эти текстбоксы редактируемые у вас? Допустим, туда ввели 10, потом подвинули слайдер, потом ввели 11? И если слайдер первый раз подвинули  до 50% - все значения уменьшились вдвое (наприер, было 10, стало 5). Потом слайдер подвинули на 25%, что должен показать текстбокс? 25% от 10 или от 5?

Comment: @tym32167 Нет, текст боксы нельзя редактировать, они изменяются только за счёт слайдера

Comment: если вы используете MVVM, то вам стоит создать вьюмодель и в ней описать всю логику, и после просто прибиндить поля вьюмодели к вашим контролам. Если MVVM вам не надо и задача тольк в том, чтобы контролы зависели от слайдера, то я бы посоветовал прибиндить контролы к слайдеру через свой конвертер, который будет умножать что скажете на что скажете.